# How to get a for loop break if a certain argument is found in print()?

Tags: python, iterator

We need a function in which some attempts are being used,which are either succeeded or failed. What to do when "successful" is printed(or reached), the first function call stops and second function starts and so on?

```
def looped(operation, attempts):
  for n in range(attempts):
    if operation():
       print("Attempt " + str(n) + " successful") 
    else:
       print("Attempt " + str(n) + " failed") 

looped(op1, 4):
looped(op2, 3):
```

Comment: Do you know about the `break` statement? This seems like the simplest possible situation to use it in. Since you're in a function, `return` could also work.

Answer (score 0):

You hit on the answer in your question title: the `break` statement. This will stop your `for` loop, and continue to any other code you have in the function.

```
def looped(operation, attempts):
    for n in range(attempts):
        if operation():
            print("Attempt " + str(n) + " successful") 
            break

        else:
            print("Attempt " + str(n) + " failed") 

    do(something_else_when_successful)
```